# Tips and tools for understanding the flow of a heavily event driven application

Tags: .net, debugging

I have been given an application to support that makes heavy use of events, which makes it really hard to understand what is going on under the hood.

Can any one give me any approaches or tools that I can use that will allow me to understand the flow of what is going on?

Right now the process I have followed is:
1) Do a search in the code for keywords that I am interested in and find the code
2) Add a breakpoint
3) Check the stack trace when it breakpoints, to see where it has gone

This approach is pretty hard to visualize as it is complicated and backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion using [Resharper Call Tracking](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/03/resharper-50-preview-call-tracking/) is the absolutely best way to do this: just hit Ctrl+Alt+A on the event or callback and choose Call Destination or Call Origin

Personally I bind Call Origin and Call Destination to Alt+Shift+< and Alt+Shift+> respectively, which makes using this method even snappier.